# Construction of 3D Toric Code

Tags: resource-request, toric-code

I am currently trying to find a mathematically elegant way to describe the construction of a 3D toric code. Since most literature is on 2D toric codes I was looking there for potential clues on how to annotate this properly, but mostly I only found a textual description of taking the hyper graph product. I was wondering if there is a general notation for such construction.

Answer (score 1):

Take a cube and tesselate it with smaller cubes. Put qubits on the edges, Z-stabilizers on the edges surrounding a face, and X-stabilizers on the edges  incident to a vertex, and then identify the opposite faces for periodic boundaries. And you've got yourself a 3D toric code!

Comment: Indeed this is the most straight forward way to explain it. But I was wondering how to describe this using the hyper graph product since 2D toric codes can be described as an HGP of two classic codes and 3D as an HGP of three classic codes. But is there a proper notation for this?